# When a set of matrices has a subset whose product is zero

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, commutative-algebra

This is a "soft" question, more about abstract techniques rather than a specific technical question. In case this is inappropriate I will delete it.

Suppose that I have a set of square matrices of a given size: $M \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. My goal is to understand what is the minimal $k$ such that there are $k$ matrices in $M$ whose multiplication is zero: smallest $k$ such that there exist $M_1,\ldots,M_k \in M$ such that $M_1 M_2 \ldots M_k =0$.

Of course, if $0 \in M$, then $k =1$. If, for example, $M  = \text{GL}(n, \mathbb{R})$, then $k = \infty$, since the product of invertible matrices is also invertible.

I am trying to understand how to determine this $k$ for some set $M$, or characterize properties of the set $M$ that might shed some light on its $k$. For example, if $M$ is closed under matrix multiplication, then either $k = 1$ or $k = \infty$.

Is this a known question? Are there known approaches for it?

Edit: another observation by Dietrich Burde mentioned in the comments, if $M$ contains a nilpotent matrix $A$ with $A^t = 0$, then the $k$ of $M$ is bounded by $t$.

Comment: If the set contains a nilpotent matrix $A$, then $A^k=0$ with the minimal $k$, which is less or equal to $n$. A general rule might be difficult. What about taking $n=2$ as an example first?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Trying now with $n=2$.

Comment: Would it be possible to first reduce your set of matrices? As you mentioned, the product of invertible matrices cannot be zero but can we simply disregard the invertible matrices without altering the smallest such $k$? (I don't think so, so reducing techniques might be difficult).

Comment: I was thinking about defining some "quotient set" of $M$, but I didn't have anything concrete. Maybe I don't have enough knowledge - may you explain a bit more about reducing techniques? Thanks!

Comment: I'm wondering whether there are ways of replacing $M$ by subsets without altering the minimal $k$. A first completely trivial observation is that if $I_n\in M$ then we can remove this element at no cost. The question is, are there smarter ways of removing matrices from $M$? 

The example of @DietrichBurde already makes clear that it's not at all clear how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of an infinite set of $2\times 2$-matrices, which doesn't contain a nilpotent matrix (so also not the zero matrix, i.e., we have $k\ge 2$), but still has minimal $k$, namely $k=2$ then:

$$
S=\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \cr 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},\;
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \cr 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix},\;
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & r \cr 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\mid r\in \Bbb C\right\}.
$$
This shows that a general answer might be difficult, and that we can write down sets with arbitrary $k$.
Moreover, the list could be given in such a way, that we don't see immediately, where the invertible or nilpotent matrices are, or any two matrices with product zero.

So the only thing which seems possible then in general is to compute all products in an efficient way and see what the minimal $k$ then is.

Comment: Thanks! any chance of understanding the $k$ from algebraic properties of $M$? e.g. if $M$ is closed under product then the answer is trivial - are there any other algebraic properties that might be helpful?

Comment: Regarding computing all multiplications - I am more interested in the case where $M$ is infinite, so this is infeasible

Comment: Yes, my example is an infinite set, and first you would have to find out these two sepcial matrices $A,B$ with $AB=0$. This is infeasable, as you say yourself (if you only have this infinite list and do not know, where these matrices are, say, because it is written differently).